# Double click on a window based applications in QTP

Tags: listbox, qtp, hp-uft

I need to double click on a popup list in  a window based application and we're using UFT. Tried so much online but couldn't get any info. Does anybody help what function to use? Also tried Dblclick function with X, Y values but didn't work.

Comment: why dont you use `WinObject.Click` two times?

Comment: If you can show the code you've written it will be easier to try and help you out.  As it stands you are not providing enough information to make this question answerable.  Read [ask] and [mcve] and edit the question to provide more detail.

Comment: Then i have to click two times quickly to select the value, else its not being selected. I'm not sure if there's a function to do so!